# OwlCarousel 1.3.2 Infinite Loop

Tags: jquery-plugins, carousel, owl-carousel, infinite-carousel

Yeah i have an old project with version 1.3.2. 
Basically the problem is when it reaches the end of the slides it does a roll back to 1st one -by seeing all previous in the process. I want after e.g. the 6th to go to the 1st as it was simply the 1st slide and not go back and view the 5th, 4th etc all the way back to 1st, ohpe the infinite looping is that feature.

I 1st tried the Owlcarousel2 (https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2) (swapped the owl.carousel.js and kept the owl.theme.css and owl.carousel.css)...my slider disappeared. Then I heard of a beta 2.0 which is compatible with the prev versions but https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel is down, I got version 1.3.3 from https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel but still and added the loop:true property, still nothing, anyone has the OwlCarousel 2.0.0-beta ?

EDIT: I found a repository of the 2.0.0 beta..same result with the OwlCarousel2 even if it had 2 css like the 1.x version it did not worked. anyone who had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

owlcarousel v1.3.3 is obsolete (don't support infinite loop),
new version is v2 in https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ (support infinite loop)